# Understanding this implementation of reverse list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have written the following  small knowledge base for reversing a given list,

```
reverse_list([],[]).
reverse_list([X|L1], [L2|X]) :-
   reverse_list(L1, L2).
```

Currently, when executed

```
reverse_list([a,b,c,d], X).
```

It produces,

```
X = [[[[[]|d]|c]|b]|a].
```

An explanation of why it happens would be much appreciated. And, how can I get around this problem?

I think at last step L2 becomes [] and during back propagation it becomes like that. 
How can I get the output like , `X = [d,c,b,a]` using a modification of this approach.

P.S: I am new at Prolog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reverse a list you need three parameters :

```
reverse_list(L,L1):-reverse_list(L,[],L1).
reverse_list([],ACC,ACC).
reverse_list([X|L], ACC,L1):- reverse_list(L,[X|ACC],L1).
```

First you call `reverse_list(L,L1)` which calls `reverse_list(L,[],L1).` where second parameter is working as an accumulator storing all the element in reverse order of your first list.
So it calls  `reverse_list([X|L1], ACC,L).` where in the first call ACC (accumulator) is empty list, then you call recursively `reverse_list(L1,[X|ACC],L).` which is the same thing but you moved X from first list and stored to accumulator. 
Finally the process stops when the first list is empty and all element are passed to ACC with reverse order and then you unify the third List with ACC.

As an example:
`L=[1,2,3],ACC=[],L` isn't evaluated.
call `reverse_list([2,3],[1],L).`
in the next recursive step call reverse_list([3],[2,1],L).
call `reverse_list([],[3,2,1],[3,2,1]).` last list is unified with `ACC=[3,2,1]`.

Querying the above example gives:

```
?- reverse_list([1,2,3],L).
L = [3, 2, 1].
```

Answer (score 5):

You can reason **algebraically** about Prolog programs.

To show you one way, let us consider a *simpler* goal that also shows the problem:

```
?- reverse_list([a], Ls).
Ls = [[]|a].
```

*Why* does this hold?

**Because** this holds *if* the following holds:

```
?- [a] = [X|L1], Ls = [L2|X], reverse_list(L1, L2).
L1 = L2, L2 = [],
Ls = [[]|a],
X = a.
```

I have simply plugged in the definition of `reverse_list/2`, making this *equivalent* to the original query and therefore of course *still* showing the problem.

Now the point: We can **generalize** the query (simply leave out some goals), and *still* see the problem:

```
?- [a] = [X|L1], Ls = [L2|X].
L1 = [],
Ls = [L2|a],
X = a.
```

So it is clear that the **clause head** contains a mistake: You are describing terms of the form `[Ls|a]`. This is *not a list*, because `a` is an *atom*.

+1 for a good naming convention! `list_reversed/2` would be even better (avoiding an imperative to suggest that other modes of use also make sense), and there may be even better names.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

You have observed a problem with your program and @mat showed you why the answer given was incorrect. Here is another way to localize the problem: Simply stick to what you expect! In your case, this would be:

```
?- reverse_list([a,b,c,d], [d,c,b,a]).
   false.  % unexpected failure
```

So here you state that this should be the case, but it is not. Therefore, your program is too specialized for the query. It lacks this solution.

To find the responsible part in your program, you can now generalize your program **such that the goal still fails**.

```
:- op(950, fy, *). % prefix *, see this for more.
*(_).

reverse_list([],_/*[]*/).
reverse_list([X|L1], [L2|X]) :-
   * reverse_list(L1, L2).
```

So I have removed the goal in the rule and the second argument in the fact - and still the program fails!  You now need to modify something in the remaining visible part in order to fix the problem.

```
reverse_list([X|L1], [L2|X])
              ^          ^
```

The `X` occurs once as an element and as a list.

There is an easy convention to avoid such errors: Name lists preferably with an added plural-`s`. So if you have an element `X`, call the list `Xs` and together this would be `[X|Xs]`. In this manner the problem would be easier to spot:

```
  reverse_list([X|Xs], [Ys|X]) :- ...
                           ^ suspicious!
```